# Website looks different in the same browser on MAC and PC

Tags: css, cross-browser, css-float, dreamweaver

For some reason my website looks different when viewed in the same browser but different operating system EX: MAC VS PC.

And forget about IE. It looks horrible. I was thinking of adding a custom css file just for IE.

It also looks different in chrome and in safari. I want all the versions to look like chrome "MAC".

The thing that specifically concerns me is the `<div id=items>`.

`http://www.amas.net/new_site/amas/index_copy.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of absolute positioned elements like:

```
#sale_items, #viewed_items, #new_items {
```

Make sure anything that will be absolute is contained in a container with position set to relative that way your layout wont break and should be more consistent

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use a css framework to minimize visual differences between rendering engines?